# How do I get Uxie?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I know this is a frequently asked question, but I still haven't found an answer.I have killed him once, and tried the time cheat, but that was all months ago.  I have caught both of the other two lake pokemon, but I've entered the Nameless Cavern at 20:30 and still nothing...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That's because Uxie can be found between 20:00 and 21:00.

Source [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/omegarubyalphasapphire/legendary.shtml).

Comment: Sorry, I meant 8:30pm

Comment: Uhm, are you doing everything right? If so, try beating Elite Four again, that should trigger the respawn.

Comment: Cheers, will try to. I'll send results by weekend.